# Jquery $.get variable not working

Tags: jquery, mysql

Can someone explain to me what i do wrong?
In Below code the varibale "getunique: d" is not working for grepping something from my mysql database.

If i change variable "getunique: d" in "getunique: '27-04'" all work good.

not working version:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  var d = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1);
  dates.push(d);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);

  $.get("../../includes/api.php", {
    getunique: d //-->> This line is not working "getunique: '27-04'" will work
  }).done(function(data) {
    var sdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    counts.push(sdata.length);
    alert(d + '---' + data);
  });
}
```

Output:
    29-4---false

Working version:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  var d = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1);
  dates.push(d);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);

  $.get("../../includes/api.php", {
    getunique: "27-04" //-->> This line is not working "getunique: '27-04'" will work
  }).done(function(data) {
    var sdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    counts.push(sdata.length);
  });
}
```

Output: 
    29-4---[{"ip":"192.168.178.143","0":"192.168.178.143"}, 
    {"ip":"192.168.178.185","0":"192.168.178.185"}]

Comment: what do you mean by not working? What error do you get?

Comment: If i put in getunique: '27-04' i get an array in return. if d is set as varibale i get nothing.

Comment: So what is value of `d` when it doesn't work? Easy enough to inspect what is actually being sent in dev tools network and/or log that value in console

Comment: Both send the same.  Types both string. Values both the same..

Comment: Suspect not and you are likely missing leading `0` in month value. If `04` works as month you are not creating that leading zero

Comment: Nope dates are the same

Comment: Well either what is being sent isn't right or back end isn't right. If you say what is sent is same must be back end problem

Comment: They're clearly not the same, just add `alert(d)`: try this in your browser console: `var date =  new Date(); date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1)` == `"29-4"`

Comment: Lol now i see it ;) It was the stupid 0! Thxs guys. Time to stop for today i think.

Comment: You can't run asynchronous HTTP requests in a `for` loop. The loop will be done *way* before even the first of your requests has a response. Refer to the duplicate thread for ways of dealing with this.